# How to get my network adapter IP with python?

Tags: python

If I type "ipconfig" in cmd, its gives some IPs... I need the one who belongs to my network adapter\internal IP.
So. for example:
If I have 3 Ips:

```
10.100.102.2
192.168.231.1
192.168.233.1
```

And I need the first one. How do I make python know that this is the one I need\The one belongs to my internal IP?

Comment: They're all internal IPs.

Comment: @Barmar Some of them belong to the VMware for example... I need the one that actually belongs to my computer (For example - just with this IP, I can connect 2 sockets between to different computer on the same Lan)

Comment: so, you are using Python on Windows?

Comment: You could look at the adapter type, to see if it's a real interface or a virtual adapter.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Your cant be more right then that :)

Comment: @Barmar Every virtual adapter will have the prefix "VMware"? if it is, so its not a problem... But - there is can be more IPs in the future that not belong to my real interface and doesnt marked as "VMware" prefix?

Comment: Instead of excluding VMWare, look specifically for the type of the real adapter. What do you want to do if you have more than one NIC on the machine?

Comment: @Barmar If I have more then one NIC on my computer it doesnt matter, because any socket will connect to it.
How can I ask the cmd just for the NIC IPs?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for extracting the first **IPv4** address of ethernet adapter (Python on Windows):
- used modules: `os`, `re`

```
import os, re

addresses = os.popen('IPCONFIG | FINDSTR /R "Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection .* Address.*[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"')
first_eth_address = re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b', addresses.read()).group()

print(first_eth_address)
```

Comment: You didnt got me well...I dont want the first one. I want the one which belongs to my LAN. The code you gave me, can gives me the virtual ip one.

Comment: I don't think that that's a big problem. Just use more specific regex condition. Check my update